# Conflict between jedi-vim and gitgutter

Tags: vim, jedi-vim

I'm using gvim 7.4 on Windows 7.
When I edited python file using jedi-vim and entered Insert Mode, cmd.exe launched many times and the vim didn't work correctly. (Sometimes the cursol couldn't be moved to the end of line.)

Why does it happen?

I wanted to debug jedi-vim, but I couldn't find a way to know what codes were executed in cmd.exe. I suppose something related the "jedi-call-signatures" might launch cmd.exe. It was fixed when I deactivate "gitgutter" plugin.

Answer (score 2):

To see / debug the external commands, you can

```
:set shellcmdflag=/k
```

This turns `cmd.exe`'s `/C`lose into `/K`eep, so you can read the command, and only then continue.

Another good debugging tip is `:set verbose=20`; this will echo every executed command. You can combine this with the `'verbosefile'` option to redirect this into a file.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably caused by the gitgutter plugin calling out to the shell to get the git-diff output of your buffer. The most simple solution would be to simply disable the plugin on Windows and to discuss this issue with the plugin developer.